# Azure Blob Storage: Can create and delete containers - not able to list or read blobs

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-blob-storage

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(
    account_url='https://XYZ.blob.core.windows.net',
    credential=credentials
)
```

The `DefaultAzureCredential` fetches my credentials I logged in with through my VS Code Azure Account plugin. The user I am logged in with has Contributor privileges - these are the same credentials picked up by `DefaultAzureCredential`.

Within the plugin I can list and read all the blobs.

With the above `blob_service_client` I can create and delete containers in the respective storage account.

Any operation that intends to list or read a blob fails with `Content: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationPermissionMismatch</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.`.

All libraries and plugins are the latest version.

Any hint as to how to resolve this would be massively appreciated.

Comment: What Azure Storage Data RBAC roles are assigned to your account? Please edit your question and provide this information.

Comment: Thank you @GauravMantri - I've added a comment on the Contributor role I am logged in with at that point.

Answer (score 0):

What you would need to do is give appropriate data related permissions to your Service Principal on a Storage Account. Please see this link for the appropriate RBAC roles that you must assign to your Service Principal to perform data related operations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory#manage-access-rights-with-rbac.